# How to do delete in DataGridView in winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

From this [MSDN Forum's answer by the moderator.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/75a312ed-de73-406a-bec5-64b62ab66925) To delete a row, **user can select the whole row, and then just use a "Delete" key to delete this row**. I am confused by this sentence.
Does it mean when I click the row I selected by mouse and hit "DEL" key on the keyboard?
If it is, it just deleted the row from the grid but not saved it in the database at all.

I doubt that the answer is wrong. How to delete the row in datagridview? I am using C# 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not delete the row from the database. You have to implement your own logic. 
Please follow this article [Insert, Update, Delete with DataGridView Control in C# (Windows Application)](http://khanrahim.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/insert-update-delete-with-datagridview-control-in-c-windows-application/)